# Ionic two images side by side full

Tags: ionic-framework

I put two `images` side by side on one page under the `header` as `col-50`. The issue is I want both images the full `50%` width without any padding around any edges. I can't seem to figure it out with `CSS`

```
  <div class="col col-50 row-no-padding">
    <img src="img/facebook.jpg" style="width:100%; display: inline-block">
    </div>

    <div class="col col-50 row-no-padding">
     <img src="img/twitter.jpg" style="width:100%; display: inline-block">
     </div>
```

The above worked in my browser (ionic serve) but did not work on my device.

Comment: can you post some code snippet of what you have done so far?

Comment: Check my post.  I edited it

Comment: What device it doesn't work on?

Comment: Can you describe how it behaves in that devices? I believe the size of the screen pushes the next block to the bottom

Comment: I figured it out.  I adding style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" to the col div.

Comment: That's great good job

Answer (score 0):

the problem is images are considered to be inline, as a result any white space is considered as space, try this:

```
<!-- both images should be in-line to have it working -->

<img style="width:50%; display: inline-block" src="the_image_source"/>

<img style="width:50%; display: inline-block;" src="the_image_source/>
```

you can also isolate the `css` if you wish

```
img{
        style: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use :

```
no-padding
```

to the col div

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6 no-padding></ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 no-padding></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

See Ionic Documentation for [Grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid)

Hope this helps.